# How to find the Average of phone calls made per District for a specific month in SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

Hi i need help in displaying a sql query

So i wanted to display the average of total number of calls made per district in a specific month, e.g january 2015, january 2016, january 2017, etc

Below is the sample database

```
id            created_on            district_name
11       January 1, 2014, 12:00 AM    azamgarh
24       January 1, 2014, 12:00 AM    badaun
7        January 1, 2014, 12:00 AM     badgam
1        January 1, 2014, 12:00 AM     bagalkot
6        January 1, 2014, 12:00 AM     baghpat
18       January 1, 2014, 12:00 AM    bahraich
4        January 1, 2014, 12:00 AM     balaghat
```

id is calls, created_on is date, district_name is district location

This is the my code regarding about this issue

```
 select
    t.district_name as "District",
    t.created_on::date as "Date",
    COUNT(t.id) AS "Total calls",
    AVG(COUNT(t.id)) OVER() as "Average"
from t
where
    date_part('month',  t.created_on::date) = 1 
    and date_part('year',  t.created_on::date) between 2013 and 2018
group by  
    date_part('year',  t.created_on::date)
    , date_part('month',  t.created_on::date)
    , district_name, created_on
```

this code only shows the total average of calls i have from 2010-2018 in the month of January instead of specific year of 2013 - 2018

Can someone help me regarding this problem? Thank you in advance

Comment: tag your dbms name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `date_part` function to `extract` and `group by`  month name and year.

```
select
    t.district_name as "District",
    t.created_on::date as "Date",
    SUM(t.id) / COUNT(t.id) as average
from t
where
    date_part('month',  t.created_on::date) = 1 
    and date_part('year',  t.created_on::date) <= 2018    
group by  
    date_part('year',  t.created_on::date)
    , date_part('month',  t.created_on::date)
    , district_name
```

Comment: how you know dbms name?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin, by this one ::date, casting, the month() function is not recognized by postgresql

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ when i try running your code, the system found an error, ERROR: syntax error at or near "created_on" Position: 215, is it because of the function or there's a problem with the variable naming?

Comment: @WilliamAdriel why not you have taged your question

Comment: @WilliamAdriel, try now, i copied your column naming

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ it only displays the first 7 days of year 2010, the rest of year 2011-2018 does not show up...

Comment: I updated the group by, pls check then, if you have some sample data, much better

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ system shows error, ERROR: column "t.created_on" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function Position: 169 .             
i've put some sample data in it, id is the total number of calls made per district (data span from 2010-2019)

Answer (score 0):

Use direct date comparisons:

```
SELECT t.district_name as "District",
       t.created_on::date as "Date",
       SUM(t.id) / COUNT(t.id) as average
FROM t
WHERE created_on >= '2018-01-01' AND
      created_on < '2018-02-01'
GROUP BY created_on::date, district_name;
```

When possible you do not want to use functions on columns in the `where` clause.  Here are three reasons:

- It prevents the use of indexes that use the column.
- It prevents the use of partitions that use the column.
- It impedes the optimizer, because it limits the use of table statistics.

In addition, you want to aggregate by the *date* without the time component, so the `GROUP BY` has also been modified.

Comment: if i use this query, won't it be only finding 1 specific month in that year only? I need to find 1 specific month for a range of 8 years

Comment: @WilliamAdriel . . . I think I misread the original question.  Your comment is correct.